# How to fix add to cart button on click add item into cart without page redirect

Tags: ajax, bigcommerce

i have big commerce website 
current issue add to cart button any user click on button that time redirect cart page i dont want this.

i want to add item into cart without page load.

i have html code how to do with AJAX.

i have try with vault cool free theme

$(function () {

}

0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable the modal and keep the shopper on the product page, you can comment out `this.previewModal.open();` in product-details.js:

```
  if (this.previewModal) {
                //this.previewModal.open();

                this.updateCartContent(this.previewModal, response.data.cart_item.id);
            } else {
                this.$overlay.show();
                // if no modal, redirect to the cart page
                this.redirectTo(response.data.cart_item.cart_url || this.context.urls.cart);
            }
```

Comment: in big commerce there is not any file product-details.js
big commerce now allowed to edit there js files.

on theme there is not modal concept , this solution was  not work.

Comment: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api-docs/cart-and-checkout/add-to-cart-url  

this a reference guide i have try with j query but variable not passing

Comment: You can edit the JS files in your theme--you'd just need to use Stencil CLI: https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/installing-stencil-cli/installing-stencil. You could create your own add to cart button using jQuery and the add-to-cart URLs, but we'd need more info on what error you're getting/what you're trying to be able to help you. The product ID is available through {{product.id}} in the template.

Comment: Also, in the Vault Cool theme, the product-details.js file is located at `assets/js/theme/common/product-details.js`. Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for guide, but easy solution for that add ajax call